# How create hyperlinks in a loop? Tkinter widget, Python

Tags: python, tkinter

The following loop unintentionally associates all the links with the last link found in brand_url[i], how can this be corrected?

```
for i in databrand.index:
    brand_name = databrand['Brands'][i]
    brand_url = databrand['Url'][i]
    link_text = brand_name + " " + brand_url
    my_link = tk.Label(right_frame, text= link_text,
                       fg="blue", cursor="hand2", font=['Times', 22, 'underline'])
    my_link.pack()
    my_link.bind("<Button-1>",
                 lambda e: webbrowser.open_new(brand_url))

    text = tk.Label(right_frame, text=databrand['Brands'][i], font=['Times', 22, 'bold'])

    text.pack()
    print(databrand['Brands'][i])
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the `lambda` to be like this: `lambda e,url=brand_url: webbrowser.open_new(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to how variables are bound in Python, you'll need one more level of indirection to bind the lambda's `url` to a local name that doesn't change:

```
def make_opener(url):
   return lambda e: webbrowser.open_new(url)

# ...

my_link.bind("<Button-1>", make_opener(url))
```